# Listening on USB port for data in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, usb

I am wanting to send data over the usb on the iphone and have it captured by my application.  This application will be private and not sold.  I would also like to just use the standard usb cable that is standard.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with Apple's [MFI Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). The downside is this will probably be quite expensive and you will of course have to develop a piece of hardware that can be sold as a product for your application.

EDIT: If you look at the 'iOS Accessories' section on the MFI Program link above, it suggests that you can communicate over the 30-pin usb dock connector.

Comment: what if it is a private application that only i will use and I am using the standard usb cable that comes standard?

Comment: If its a private application you might want to look at how jailbreak hackers develop their apps. You should be able to do the same with the SDK but I'd imagine that community might be able to help you out more!